# How does Sundial of the Infinite help you avoid losing turns to Eater of Days?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

This [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20151228222002/http://archive.wizards.com:80/Magic/magazine/Article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/ftl/259) on Wizards of the Coast website claims that [Eater of Days](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Eater%20of%20Days) "lose your next two turns" can be avoided by use of [Sundial of the Infinite](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sundial%20of%20the%20Infinite).  I can't figure that out.  There are no rulings on Eater of Days, and it is not an "end of turn" type of effect.  Is the author just wrong?  [seems unlikely]  Or maybe the rules have changed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A ruling on Sundial of the Infinite says

> Ending the turn this way means the following things happen in order: 1) **All spells and abilities on the stack are exiled.** This includes spells and abilities that can't be countered. 2) All attacking and blocking creatures are removed from combat. 3) State-based actions are checked. No player gets priority, and no triggered abilities are put onto the stack. 4) The current phase and/or step ends. The game skips straight to the cleanup step. The cleanup step happens in its entirety.

Eater of Days' ability is a triggered ability, so if you respond to it by activating Sundial of the Infinite, that triggered ability will be exiled and will never resolve. So, you don't have to skip any turns.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the pointer @murgatroid99.  That wasn't enough for me to "get" it, but it was enough for me to fill in the gaps!!

Answer (score 8):

Yes, Sundial of the Infinite can be used to avoid skipping your next two turns. Here is what happens in more detail:

1. You have [Sundial of the Infinite](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSundial%20of%20the%20Infinite%5d) on the board.
2. You cast [Eater of Days](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEater%20of%20Days%5d).
3. Eater of Days enters the battlefield, and its triggered ability, "When Eater of Days enters the battlefield, you skip your next two turns." is put on the stack.
   *Note*: triggered abilities are defined in detail in comprehensive rule 603.
4. You activate Sundial of the Infinite's ability.
5. Everyone passes priority.  (i.e. it is possible for an opponent to respond to Sundial of the Infinite's activation)
6. Step (1) of of Sundial of the Infinite's ability exiles "you skip your next two turns" from the stack.
   *Note*: The details of how to resolve Sundial of the Infinite's ability is covered in comprehensive rule 713.

At present, three cards can stop a turn.  [Sundial of the Infinite](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSundial%20of%20the%20Infinite%5d), [Time Stop](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTime%20Stop%5d) and [Obeka, Brute Chronologist](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bObeka%2c%20Brute%20Chronologist%5d).  The rulings on those cards are consistent, but different, and it's worth reading all of them to understand the implications.

Comment: You can always just ask the author of an answer for clarification.

Comment: yeah, I know, but I am trying to "learn how to fish" when it comes to mtg rules.  On this particular question I didn't even know where to start.  murgatroid99 got me on the right path, and since I came up with what to me was an essentially completely different answer, I figured I'd just supply it.

Comment: "a little more detail" as you said in the answer seems more accurate than "completely different answer" - it's the same reason, with an added explanation of what a triggered ability is. Personally my inclination in cases like that is to suggest adding the detail to the existing answer (all the better if you've figured out yourself what needs to be added), but this is a good answer too.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @beam022 I am not following the point you are trying to make.

Comment: @John It means that he saw your question in the review queue and choose to recommend deletion, with the reason "This is commentary on another post, not an answer." That automatically adds the comment you see. He's saying that your answer is more like a comment on my answer than a standalone answer.

Comment: I think your opening sentence and first person point of view are confusing everyone. I'm going to rewrite your answer using second person point of view, and remove the opening sentence. Then it will just look like you are answering your own question, which is a completely fine thing to do. Feel free to roll it back.

Comment: @John Can you explain why you think this answer is different from mine. Both answers mention that Eater of Days' ability is a triggered ability, that you can respond to it by activating Sundial of the Infinite, and what part of Sundial's ability exiles Eater of Days' ability. I can't tell what your answer adds.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I think it's the fact that it explicitly says what the triggered ability is, and that it goes on the stack. But I'm not too confident, since your answer was awfully close to saying that too. (And I'm not too impressed with the idea of finding another answer to be missing detail and responding like this.)